# Aptitude installing jre

Tags: terminal, apt, java, aptitude, kali-linux

I am trying to install jre on my debian 7 kali box, but I keep getting these faulty errors. I tried installing it through aptitude and it fails at the end.

The result is:

```
dpkg: error processing default-jre-headless (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64
openjdk-7-jre:amd64
icedtea-7-jre-jamvm:amd64
openjdk-7-jdk:amd64
openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64
openjdk-6-jre:amd64
openjdk-6-jre-lib
default-jre
icedtea-6-jre-cacao:amd64
icedtea-netx:amd64
icedtea-6-jre-jamvm:amd64
default-jre-headless
```

I have no idea what the problem is. Can anyone help me with this issue, please?

Comment: what is the exact command that you are running ?

Comment: Well I just typed: aptitude install default-jre:i386

Comment: unrelated: I have seen people installing jdk via aptitude and not jre.

Comment: Odd, that means the dependencies weren't satisified, but aptitude should have resolved them. What does `apt-get -f install` give?

Comment: apt-get -f install gives the same error.

with: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

at the end.

Comment: @Debian4Ever You'd first try to update the package list: `apt-get update` and if you can't still install jre, then try to update the whole system's packages: `apt-get upgrade`.